# getJSONArray from root objects in JSON format - Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, object

I've been spending the last couple of days trying to format a JSON string into a JSON object, but this is not quite the usual json string. Im receiving it from an url and have no problem converting it into a string but when im going to create the JSON object Ive found a whole lot of issues.
The JSON looks like this:

```
header {
  gtfs_realtime_version: "1.0"
  incrementality: FULL_DATASET
  timestamp: 1511789066
}
entity {
  id: "294-131-39-562-4732025"
  vehicle {
    trip {
      trip_id: "131-39-562-4732025"
      route_id: "131"
    }
    position {
      latitude: 3.44351
      longitude: -76.52622
    }
    timestamp: 1511789065
    stop_id: "501450"
    vehicle {
      id: "21002"
      label: "MC21002"
      license_plate: "VCQ452"
    }
  }
}
entity {
  id: "1087-431-55-35-4732025"
  vehicle {
    trip {
      trip_id: "431-55-35-4732025"
      route_id: "431"
    }
    position {
      latitude: 3.3767517
      longitude: -76.54276
    }
    timestamp: 1511789065
    stop_id: "502150"
    vehicle {
      id: "31038"
      label: "MC31038"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see there is no array, nor commas separating the element that I need to process (entity), I cant even get the JSONObject from the root.
Any suggestions?
This is the last block of code I've tried in which I remove the header, insert all the entity objects into the array buses, and separate them by commas, but is no use

```
//getRespuesta(); gives me the string 
//Log.d("LIVE", "RAW JSon: " + getRespuesta()); 
String[] parts = getRespuesta().split("[}]", 2);


String[] splitter = parts[1].split("(?=entity)");

String finalString = splitter[1];

for (int t = 2; t < splitter.length; t++) {
    finalString = finalString + ",\n" + splitter[t];
}

Log.d("LIVEL", "SIZE: " + splitter[1]);

String JSonChunk = "{ \n \"buses\": [ \n " + finalString + "\n ] \n }";
//String JSonChunk = "{ \n " + parts[1] + "\n }";
try {


   // Log.d("LIVE", "CHUNKED JSon: " + JSonChunk);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSonChunk);
}catch........
```

Comment: The problem is that this is not `JSON`.

Comment: You need to create a custom program that converts what you got to valid `JSON`.

Comment: That looks like protobuf.

Comment: That string does not have a compatible JSON structure.  The keys, for example, must be wrapped by quotes.  Further, the "JSON objects" are not separated by a comma.

Comment: Instead of forcing this essentially non-JSON through a JSON parser, it's probably easier to parse each line with regular expressions.

Comment: Don't use regex, instead find out what format the string is in and use the appropriate parser for that format. Where does this data come from?

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments and as you've seen you can't use a JSON parser on non-JSON.  I'd take the following approach:

1. If this meets the specifications of a known format, someone has probably written a JSON converter you can run it through.
2. If it is a custom format but each line is a predictable format and *does not rely on anything before or after*, you can run *each line* through a custom converter and give it the 'JSON-ness.' (add commas, etc)  Process each line at at time rather than trying to split up the whole thing at once.
3. If none of the above are true, you need to go into regular expression hell.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you must transform it to a valid JSON String

You can try this regex:
https://regex101.com/r/15dHwd/1

That means, for each group that capture tou replace it with ": {"
That way: "position {" will re replaced with "position: {"

Now you have other issue,
"entity" appears twice

If you are 100% sure that you will get always that format, after the first replace:

Start with appending "{" on the beginning of the string

1. Get a regex to find the "entity" String
2. Replace the first match with "array: [ entity"
3. List item
4. On the end of the string append: "]}"